# presentModalViewController out of screenrage to get custom animation

Tags: ios, uiview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I need a presentModalViewController animation like UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical but from left and right instead from bottom.
The only thing to solve that problem is i need to present the new view with presentModalViewController out of the current view range and call a simple animation.
But i can not find a solution to present the new view with presentModalViewController out of the screen range.

Answer (score 3):

That is:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
// parent.view.window.layer is essential!
[parent.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil ];
[parent presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```